# How to create webservices from Magento for mobile app android

Tags: android, web-services, magento

The eCommerce site was developed using Magento. So, we need mobile app for that website. We need to access the web services generated from Magento to access data in mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to go `Magento` admin panel then you have to create user for Magento API. FOR creating user in `Magento` just goto

System->Web Services->SOAP/XML-RPC-Users

then set the roles for user from

System->Web Services->SOAP/XML-RPC-Roles

Now you can use `Magento` webservice. You can see how to use webservice from this link.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html