# Magento SOAP API with iPhone application

Tags: ios, api, rest, magento, soap

I want to use magento soap api in my iPhone application for the functions like login user, get products, buy products etc.

I checked this link [Magento SOAP API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) there some example with php. Can any one suggest how can we use this in iOS or any link? Please guide me.

Also I have go through this example [LogNMagento](https://github.com/lognllc/LogNMagento) but I am getting response 0x0 (nil) for login response.

I have set values as below

```
#ifndef MAGENTO_BASE_URL
#define MAGENTO_BASE_URL @"http://magentohost/api.php?type=soap&wsdl=1"
#endif
#ifndef MAGENTO_USERNAME
#define MAGENTO_USERNAME @"username"
#endif
#ifndef MAGENTO_API_KEY
#define MAGENTO_API_KEY @“password”
#endif
```

Please suggest where I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hope this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020251/how-to-create-webservices-from-magento-for-mobile-app-android/26022851#26022851

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use `AFNetworking` to work with `SOAP`. But, I had used [wsdl2objc tool](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) to parse `WSDL` xml file into `Obj-C` source codes about 3~4 years ago. Hope that can help you.

At that project, I had used [sudzc](http://sudzc.com/) too, but it cannot help me to solve my problem. In my case, it produces too many compiler errors and hard to fix.

Comment: Thanks Toro for the reply, I will check with that too.